# Como remover marcadores específicos de um googlemap

Tags: java, android, marker

Então, este app funciona assim: o usuário insere uma jornada que vai do ponto C (coleta) para o ponto E (entrega).

Estes pontos são mostrados no mapa, na forma de marcadores, como na figura abaixo.

[image: Exemplo de mapa com marcadores]

Agora eu preciso remover os marcadores ao clicar no X.

O conceito geral é assim: vou fazer uma lista contendo (String ID, Marker marcadorDe, Marker marcadorPara) e cada novo marcador adiciona uma linha a esta lista no método addMarker().

Dai, o método removeMarker(String ID) vai recuperar os marcadores relativos ao ID e remove-los do mapa, quando o usuário exclui a jornada.

Minha pesquisa indicou diversas abordagens possíveis. Poderia criar uma classe, uma lista, um hashmap, etc.

Gostaria da opiniões sobre a melhor forma de fazer isso e se possivel, exemplos de código.

Note que a adição dos marcadores já funciona e a remoção do registro também. E justamente neste momento que eu vou chamar o método removeMarker().

Acho que a questão pode ser resumida em: Qual a melhor maneira de criar uma lista com tipos String, Marker, Marker?

Comment: Por que não usa o id do registo na tabela do banco para id do marker?

Comment: o ID já é o id da tabela. Não quero reconstruir o mapa a cada exclusão. Então, ao montar o mapa, o app guarda uma lista com cada par de marcadores e o ID do registro para usar mais tarde, na exclusão. Minha questão é justamente, qual seria a melhor forma de guardar estes valores: criando array, objeto, hashmap, etc? O que vc acha?

Comment: Normalmente o que se usa é um HashMap. Use o id como key e, como valor, um objecto de uma classe que guarde os dois Marker.

Comment: Justo. Deu certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução ficou assim.

No listener do botão excluir (X) do adaptador do recyclerView, deletamos o registro e em seguida, chamamos o método na MainActivity:

```
holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            ...  
            runDbHelper.deleteRow(runId);
            ((MainActivity) v.getContext()).removeMarkersFromMap(runId);
            ...
            ... 
        }
    });
```

O método de remoção na MainActivity, recebe o ID e repassa para o fragmento:

```
public  void removeMarkersFromMap(String ID) {
    if (ID != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MarkersFragment mFragment = null;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mFragment = (MarkersFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.markersMapPanel);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            mFragment = (MarkersFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
        }
        if (mFragment != null) {
            mFragment.removeMarkers(ID);
        }
    }

}
```

Este, por sua vez, executa o método no fragmento do mapa que exclui o(s) marcador(es).

```
public void removeMarkers(String id){

    MarkersPair markersPair = markersPairHashMap.get(id);
    if(markersPair != null){
        if(markersPair.collect != null) {
            markersPair.collect.remove();
        }
        if(markersPair.delivery != null) {
            markersPair.delivery.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

e, finita la comedia!

Answer (score 0):

Tenho uma tela que exibe alguns pontos num mapa; de acordo com a ação do usuário é preciso atualizar esse mapa escondendo/exibindo alguns marcadores. O que fizemos foi manter os pontos já carregados e controlar estas ações no `javascript`.

```
var marcadores = {}; //seria array de [ID] -> marcadores

...
function LimparMarcadores () {
    for (var i = 0; i < marcadores[id].length; i++) {
        if (marcadores[id][i] != "0")
            marcadores[id][i].setMap(null);
    }

    marcadores[id] = [];
}
```

Comment: A pergunta refere as tags `Android` e `java`.